# Globally defined solutions in bc CFT system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, topology

Consider $bc$-system which is 2-dimensional CFT of fermions:

$S = \int_\Sigma d^2 z \  b \bar{\partial} c + h.c.  $

where $\Sigma$ -  2-dimensional manifold of genus $p$, fields $b, c$ have dimensions $(\lambda, 0)$ and $(1-\lambda, 0)$ respectively.

The question is to find number of globally defined solutions of equations of motion 
$\bar{\partial} b = 0, \bar{\partial} c = 0$ and for Sphere and Torus find these solutions explicitly.

The problem is that I don't even understand, what does "globally defined" mean, and why solutions may be not globally defined, what is the problem here.

I've been told that it's somehow connected to Riemann-Roch theorem, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. Given a [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) $M$, the word *locally* is associated with an open neighborhood $U\subseteq M$, while the word *globally* refers to the whole manifold $M$.
2. If $E\to M$ is a [fiber bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle), let $E_{|U}\to U$ denote the restriction of the bundle $E\to M$ to the neighborhood $U\subseteq M$. For instance, if $s\in\Gamma(E_{|U}\to U)$ is a locally-defined [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28fiber_bundle%29), it may or may not be possible to extend $s$ to a globally defined section $\tilde{s}\in\Gamma(E\to U)$ such that the restriction $\tilde{s}_{|U}=s$.
3. Now the ghost fields $b$ and $c$ are sections in appropriate [vector bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) over a [Riemann surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) $M=\Sigma$.
4. The [Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem)  (and more generally, the [Atiyah–Singer index theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem)) yields information about the dimension of the space of globally defined sections over certain vector bundles.